# How to debug a DEVICE-DEPENDENT WebView and/or WebViewClient anomaly?

Tags: android, post, webview, http-post, android-webview

In one of my classes, I call [WebView.postUrl()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#postUrl%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D%29):

```
getWebView().postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

Which works perfectly on an LG Optimus S, but doesn't work for some reason on an HTC Nexus One.

By "works" I mean that the target site responds to the postUrl() query with the expected results and is characterized by always:

1. generating **two** `WebViewClient.onPageStarted()` calls,
2. followed by a `WebView.loadUrl()` and
3. followed by a `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`

On the culprit Nexus One, however, only the first `WebViewClient.onPageStarted()` call is generated, never followed by any other call.

Obviously WebView and/or WebViewClient are behaving differently on the different devices, because both devices run the **same exact application code**.

(or is it the website that's responding differently to the different devices, which use the same exact WiFi gateway?)

Both devices run the same exact application code, but the Android versions are slightly different: The LG runs 2.3.3 and the N1 runs 2.2.1.

Any idea or tips on how to approach the debugging of this tough problem?

For example, are there any hooks that I can place somewhere to trace what's really going on under the cover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override onReceivedSslError and onReceivedError of your WebViewClient. I'm guessing it is an issue with 2.2 not trusting certain CAs, or a bug that causes problems wildcard domains in SSL  certificates - both of these specific errors will be caught in onReceivedSslError.

If either of these methods gets called, the page might not get finished loading.

If there aren't any errors, your server might be doing something different because of the device's User-Agent - which you might have to manually set.

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful and much needed tip. I will implement it and report back. +1 in the meanwhile.

Comment: OK, I am back with initial results: I implemented both `onReceivedError` and `onReceivedSslError` so that they only log something on LogCat and... there are no errors whatsoever! I am not surprised about not having any `onReceivedSslError`, because it's a simply query (not necessarily via SSL), but the fact there is no received error at all suggests that your 2nd guess (user-agent dependent behavior of the server) may be the culprit. Will experiment with that shortly.

Comment: Update 2: I conducted a quick experiment by faking the UA on the NA to be exactly like the LG's (using `WebSettings.setUserAgentString`): The (odd) behavior remained the same! That is, no response of the website to `postUrl()`. I am beginning to suspect a bug in my own code... (not surprising, but how on earth do I find it, when the code behaves well on all phones except for the N1?)